# Can a magnet rotate using DC motor principles?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: What I suppose it looks like]

Considering the way a basic DC motor works, if a ring magnet (diametrically polarized) was placed around the armature with DC supply but held stationary, would the magnet rotate instead?

Also, is there such a software I could simulate/animate this on?

Comment: I believe that's how a brushless DC motor works. Look up brushless DC motor.

Comment: Yes you're right, it is similar to what I was picturing, but without adding pairs of coils would the concept not hold? I've added an image for clarification.

Comment: The above setup in the image can't run on DC, it'll spin just once and stop if connected to a DC source.

Comment: The above setup in the image can't run on DC, it'll spin just once and stop if connected to a DC source.

Comment: Makes sense. So it would need AC power or a commutator connected in some way?

Answer (score 0):

If by "diametrically polarized" you mean that the magnetic poles are on an axis perpendicular to the rotational axis, the answer is "yes".  All you need to do is put a commutator on the shaft that holds the magnet, to switch stationary electromagnets on and off as the shaft rotates.

Comment: I've added an image to the post to clarify the way I'm picturing it. If I understood your answer correctly, a commutator would need to be added to the shaft the ring is on in order to rotate the ring?

Comment: That is correct.